# Не выполняется послендий кусок кода, в чем проблема?

Tags: python

```
def isPhoneNumber(text):
    if len(text) != 12:
        return False
    for i in range(0, 3):
        if not text[i].isdecimal():
            return False
    if text[3] != '-':
        return False
    for i in range(8, 12):
        if not text[i].isdecimal():
            return False
    return True
print('455-323-1233 - это телефонный номер')
print(isPhoneNumber('453-323-1233'))
message = 'Позвони мне завтра по номеру 415-555-1011. 415-555-9999 - это телефонный номер моего офиса.'
for i in range(len(message)):
    chunk = message[i:i+12]
if isPhoneNumber(chunk):
    print('Найденный номер телефона: ' + chunk)
print(isPhoneNumber(chunk))
```

Ответ:

455-323-1233 - это телефонный номер

True

False

Comment: Так всё выполняется ведь

Answer (score 0):

Поправьте отступы

```
...
for i in range(len(message)): 
    chunk = message[i:i+12] 
    if isPhoneNumber(chunk): 
        print('Найденный номер телефона: ' + chunk) 
        print(isPhoneNumber(chunk))
```

Comment: Спасибо, исправил, вечная проблема с этими отступами, не знаете, нет ли комбинации клавиш, которая поможет редактировать весь код по стандартам отступа?

Comment: @VyacheslavBondarev, дело не в стандартах. Отступы показывают вложенность (в данном случае, вложен ли `if` внутрь цикла `for`). Если вы неправильно показали вложенность, но никакой искусственный интеллект за вас не определит правильно ли вы сделали или нет. Это не синтаксическая ошибка, а логическая.

Comment: @insolor понял, спасибо огромное, уже давно разобрался что моя логика просто не соответствует логике Python(а)